# Accessing related values on the many side of a relationship

Tags: powerbi, dax

Power BI table expansion happens only on the 1 side of the relationship.

Say table 1 is the m side and table 2 is the 1 side.

Due to the expasion we can use the corresponding value from the 1 side of the table in for example SUMX(table1, DIVIDE(table1[col1], realated(table2[col1]) )

If so then how does RELATEDTABLE formula work in case of m:1 and also in case of m:m relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Expanded table works from the many side of a relationship to the one side. In your example, table 1 expanded table contains table 2 but not vice-versa.

`table 1` * <- 1 `table 2`

this is correct

```
SUMX(table1, DIVIDE(table1[col1], related(table2[col1]) )
```

RELATEDTABLE works from the one side to the many side and it returns the table with the rows corresponding to the one side

```
SUMX(table2, COUNTROWS( RELATEDTABLE(table1) ) )
```

the many to many relatioship in DAX are not a generic many to many relationship but some sort of "one to many at a higher level of granularity".  In this case we have single direction relationships that from the point of view of the RELATEDTABLE function should behave like 1 to many relationships. RELATED instead cannot work since no single row can be returned.